# LaTeX Beamer - \beamer@centeringfalse does nothing inside \setbeamertemplate

Tags: beamer

I am trying to make a custom `beamer` title page which fills from the top down.
I can use `\beamer@centeringfalse` to change this but this is a global setting for the whole document.
When I put the command inside the `\setbeamertemplate{titlepage}`, the title page fills from the center.

Is there a way to fix this?

Code:

```
\setbeamertemplate{title page}%
{%
    \begin{tabular}{l|c|r}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.3\textwidth]{normal text}%
            \centering%
            \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor%
        \end{beamercolorbox}&%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.3\textwidth]{normal text}%
            \centering%
            \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute%
        \end{beamercolorbox}&%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.3\textwidth]{normal text}%
            \centering%
            \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate%
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth]{normal text}%
        \centering%
        \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty\else%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth]{accent text}%
        \centering%
        \begin{tikzpicture}%
        \node[draw, ellipse, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, line width=2pt, inner sep=2pt] at (2,0) {%
                                                                                        \begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}%
                                                                                            \centering%
                                                                                            \usebeamerfont{subtitle}\color{WhiteSmoke}\insertsubtitle\par%
                                                                                        \end{minipage}};%
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \fi%
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `title page` template is executed within a frame. At this point it is already too late to set frame options.

To nevertheless have control of the alignment of your title page, you could make sure that your title page fills the whole frame so `[c]`, `[t]` or `[b]` frames won't matter.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\title{text}
\author{names}
\subtitle{subtitle}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}%
{%
  \begin{minipage}[t][\textheight]{\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l|c|r@{}}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.3\textwidth]{normal text}%
            \centering%
            \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor%
        \end{beamercolorbox}&%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.3\textwidth]{normal text}%
            \centering%
            \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute%
        \end{beamercolorbox}&%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.3\textwidth]{normal text}%
            \centering%
            \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate%
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \end{tabular}%
    
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth]{normal text}%
        \centering%
        \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty\else%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth]{accent text}%
        \centering%
        \begin{tikzpicture}%
        \node[draw, ellipse, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, line width=2pt, inner sep=2pt] at (2,0) {%
                                                                                        \begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}%
                                                                                            \centering%
                                                                                            \usebeamerfont{subtitle}\color{red}\insertsubtitle\par%
                                                                                        \end{minipage}};%
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    
    \fi%
  \end{minipage}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[c]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[b]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```